# cómo almacenar una lista en Hiernate

Tags: java, mysql, lista, hibernate

Aqui esta la clase Contenedor con la Lista de PlazasBlock que es la que quiero almacenar en hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTENEDOR", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "IdContenedor")})
public class Contenedor implements Serializable {
//Atributos de la clase Contenedor

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "IdContenedor", nullable = false)
private int idContenedor; // IdContenedor del espacio que lo diferencia de los demas.
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CedulaUsuario", nullable = false)
private Usuario usuario; // Quien adquiere la reserva
@Column(name = "Tipo", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String tipo; // Genero es el tipo de espacio que se crea(salas de cine, parqueaderos...)
@Column(name = "Nombre", length = 50)
private String nombre; // Nombre que le damos al espacio a crear
@Column(name = "Descripcion", length = 500)
private String descripcion; // Descripcion que tendra cada espacio creado.
@Column(name="NFilas")
private int nFilas; // numero de filas en el contenedor
@Column(name="NColumnas")
private int nColumnas; // numero de columnas en el contenedor 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contenedor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<PlazasBlock> blockPlazas= new ArrayList();// Lista de objetos Lugar que tiene como nombre lugares.

/**
 * Constructor,se crea un objecto contenedor sin parametros
 *
 */



public Contenedor() {
}

public Contenedor(Usuario usuario, String tipo, String nombre, String descripcion, int nFilas, int nColumnas, List<PlazasBlock> blockPlazas) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.nFilas= nFilas;
    this.nColumnas=nColumnas;
    this.getBlockPlazas().clear();
    this.getBlockPlazas().addAll(blockPlazas);
}

public int getIdContenedor() {
    return idContenedor;
}

public void setIdContenedor(int idContenedor) {
    this.idContenedor = idContenedor;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario Usuario) {
    this.usuario = Usuario;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public int getnFilas() {
    return nFilas;
}

public void setnFilas(int nFilas) {
    this.nFilas = nFilas;
}

public int getnColumnas() {
    return nColumnas;
}

public void setnColumnas(int nColumnas) {
    this.nColumnas = nColumnas;
}

public List<PlazasBlock> getBlockPlazas() {
    return blockPlazas;
}

public void setBlockPlazas(List<PlazasBlock> blockPlazas) {
    this.getBlockPlazas().clear();
    this.getBlockPlazas().addAll(blockPlazas);

}
// Fin de los metodos GET Y SET de los atributos
}
```

Aqui esta la clase PlazasBlock

@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAZASBLOCK")
@IdClass(value = PlazasBlockPK.class)
public class PlazasBlock implements Serializable {
    // Atributos de la clase Plaza

```
@Id
@Column(name = "PosicionX")
public int x;
@Id
@Column(name = "PosicionY")
public int y;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdContenedor", nullable = false)
private Contenedor contenedor;

/**
 * Constructor,se crea un objeto Plaza sin parametros
 */
public PlazasBlock() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

public PlazasBlock(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public boolean equals(PlazasBlock plaza) {

    return plaza.getX() == this.x && plaza.getY() == this.y;

}

// Metodos GET Y SET de los atributos
public Contenedor getContenedor() {
    return contenedor;
}

public void setContenedor(Contenedor contenedor) {
    this.contenedor = contenedor;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
// Fin de los metodos GET y SET
```

}

El problema esta en que me guarda todos los atributos de las clases Usuario y Contenedor pero lo que esta en la List blockPlazas no me la guarda que hago?

```
private void jButton4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

String cedulaUsuario=txtCc.getText();
String nombre=txtNombre.getText();
String apellido=txtApellido.getText();
String telefono=txtTel.getText();


String nombreC=txtTitulo.getText();
String tipo=txtTipo.getText();
String descripcion=txtAreaDescripcion.getText();
int nFilas=(Integer)SpinnerFila.getValue();
int nColumnas=(Integer)SpinnerColumna.getValue();
List<PlazasBlock> blockPlazas= this.plazasBlock;

Usuario usuario=new Usuario(cedulaUsuario,nombre,apellido,telefono);
Contenedor contenedor=new Contenedor(usuario, tipo, nombreC, descripcion, nFilas, nColumnas, blockPlazas);

Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(usuario);    //<|--- Aqui guardamos el objeto en la base de datos.
session.save(contenedor); //<|--- Aqui guardamos el objeto en la base de datos.


session.flush();
session.getTransaction().commit();
NewHibernateUtil.shutdown();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Espacio creado exitosamente!!");
}
```

Le agregue la anotacion: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contenedor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
     orphanRemoval = true)
    private List blockPlazas= new ArrayList();

Pero me sale este error:
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: insert into USUARIO (Apellido, Nombre, Telefono, CedulaUsuario) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into CONTENEDOR (Descripcion, NColumnas, NFilas, Nombre, Tipo, CedulaUsuario) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select plazasbloc_.IdContenedor, plazasbloc_.PosicionX, plazasbloc_.PosicionY from PLAZASBLOCK plazasbloc_ where plazasbloc_.IdContenedor=? and plazasbloc_.PosicionX=? and plazasbloc_.PosicionY=?
Hibernate: select plazasbloc_.IdContenedor, plazasbloc_.PosicionX, plazasbloc_.PosicionY from PLAZASBLOCK plazasbloc_ where plazasbloc_.IdContenedor=? and plazasbloc_.PosicionX=? and plazasbloc_.PosicionY=?
Hibernate: insert into PLAZASBLOCK (IdContenedor, PosicionX, PosicionY) values (?, ?, ?)
oct 09, 2018 7:51:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
oct 09, 2018 7:51:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Column 'IdContenedor' cannot be null
oct 09, 2018 7:51:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)

Comment: Igual estaría bien que pusieras cómo es la clase 'PlazasBlock'

Comment: Ya coloque la clase PlazasBlock ayuda por favor

Comment: Te está diciendo que idContenedor no puede ser null

Comment: Y que tengo mal para que salga ese error?

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un detalle en la anotación:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contenedor",
     fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
     cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
     orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PlazasBlock> blockPlazas= new ArrayList();
```

Con estos atributos le dices a Hibernate que si hay un cambio en la lista también quede reflejado en la base de datos, tanto si borras como si añades elementos.

Comment: Le colocque la anotacion pero ahora me sale este error:

Comment: Puedes poner el error en la pregunta? no sale en el comentario

Comment: Ya coloque el error por favor ayuda